# Failed to start ~~~.service in linux18.04, systemd service Program

Tags: linux, service, server, daemon, systemd

I'm setting up a new service program.
I use `systemctl`. but when I authorized, enabled, started the service
but it didn't work with error 'Failed to start ~~~.service.

> I commanded this commands.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start serverProgram.service
sudo systemctl enable serverProgram.service
sudo systemctl status serverProgram.service
```

and error code is like this.

```
serverProgram.service : Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
serverProgram.service : Scheduled restart job, restart counter is a 5. Stopped serverProgram.service.
serverProgram.service : Start request repeated too quickly.
serverProgram.service : Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start serverProgram.service.
```

I wrote `serverProgram.service` with nano.
and the code is like this.

```
# serverProgram file

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/Desktop/LSH/Study/C++/DaemonProgram
ExecStart=/home/Desktop/LSH/Study/C++/DaemonProgram/main
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to activate main program automatically in reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the program you're trying to run is failing as soon as you try to run it. `systemd` is trying to restart it (because you have `Restart=always`), but it gives up if it detects a lot of restarts in a very short period.

If your program is OK when you run it manually, remember that `systemd` will be trying to run it in a different role than you would normally (different user, different environment settings etc.)

You should be able to see the output of your program using `journalctl` - [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115513/163349) has a quick example on how to use it.